# linklint error: can only check case under Windows/Dos

Tags: perl

I am running the following command on Windows cygwin

```
perl ../../donotship/linklint-2.3.5/linklint-2.3.5 -silent -quiet -case -orphan -error -warn -xref -doc WinNT_Debug/report -out WinNT_Debug/report/report.txt -root WinNT_Debug/ship /@s
```

This command fails by saying **linklint error: can only check case under Windows/Dos**, I am running on Windows only. If I remove case option it works fine.

How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

My System path has Two cygwins, Removing one cygwin from path solves this issue